# Data_Frame Error - ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two data_frames, as below:

```
df_name:
   Student_ID  Name        DOB
0           1  Raju 1993-02-02
1           2  Indu 1987-01-04
2           3  Laya 2000-06-24
```

```
df_marks:
    Student_ID Subject  Int1/40  Int2/40
0            1     Eng       10       35
1            1     Tam       30       38
2            1     Mat       20       30
3            1     Sci       15       20
4            2     Eng       35       25
5            2     Tam       25       15
6            2     Mat       22       30
7            2     Sci       29       23
8            3     Eng       18       17
9            3     Tam       19       16
10           3     Mat       27       26
```

The task is to create a data_frame(below one), where I need to add `df_marks['Int1/40']` & `df_marks['Int2/40']`, if `df_name['Student_ID'] == df_marks['Student_ID']`

```
   Student_id  Name        DOB  Tam/50
0           1  Raju 1993-02-02     NaN
1           2  Indu 1987-01-04     NaN  
2           3  Laya 2000-06-24     NaN
```

I tried

```
df_out['Tam/50'] = df_marks[['Int1/40','Int2/40']].sum(axis=1).where(df_marks['Subject']==df_out['Student_id'])
```

But its giving error as,

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Do we have any simple way to do this?

Regards,
Deepak Dash

Comment: What is `df_out`? And why are you comparing `df_marks['Subject']==df_out['Student_id']`? Please edit your question properly with correct expected output.

Comment: Basically df_out is my output data frame, I need to add the columns('Int1/40' , 'Int2/40'), if Student_ID matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with aggregated `sum` for new column in `df_name`:

```
df_marks['Tam/50'] = df_marks[['Int1/40','Int2/40']].sum(axis=1)
df_name = df_name.join(df_marks.groupby('Student_ID')['Tam/50'].sum(), on='Student_ID')
print (df_name)
   Student_ID  Name         DOB  Tam/50
0           1  Raju  1993-02-02     198
1           2  Indu  1987-01-04     204
2           3  Laya  2000-06-24     123
```

Or solution without helper column:

```
s = (df_marks[['Int1/40','Int2/40']].sum(axis=1)
                                    .groupby(df_marks['Student_ID'])
                                    .sum()
                                    .rename('Tam/50'))

df_name = df_name.join(s, on='Student_ID')
print (df_name)
   Student_ID  Name         DOB  Tam/50
0           1  Raju  1993-02-02     198
1           2  Indu  1987-01-04     204
2           3  Laya  2000-06-24     123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to match both data frames on `Student_ID`. Then use `groupby` and `sum`:

```
In [574]: res = pd.merge(df_name, df_marks,on='Student_ID')
In [592]: r = res.groupby(['Student_ID', 'Name', 'DOB'])[['Int1/40','Int2/40']].sum(1).reset_index()

In [594]: r['Tam/50'] = r['Int1/40'] + r['Int2/40']
In [604]: r.drop(['Int1/40', 'Int2/40'], 1, inplace=True)

In [605]: r
Out[605]: 
   Student_ID  Name         DOB  Tam/50
0           1  Raju  1993-02-02     198
1           2  Indu  1987-01-04     204
2           3  Laya  2000-06-24     123
```